# Как работает оператор xor?

Tags: ruby, битовые-операции, логика, логические-выражения, xor

Например, есть задание найти уникальное значение в массиве:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Можно сделать:

```
a.inject(:^)
```

Результатом будет **5**. Т.е. он будет сравнивать результат предыдущего вычисления с новым элементом - `(1^2)^3`.

Но как это работает в данном примере я не понимаю. Почему возвращается **5**? С `true/false` или `1/0` понятно, но почему `(1^2)` вернет `3`, а следом `(3^3)` возвращает `0`.

Интересно было бы узнать и фундаментально (как применять `XOR`) и как это работает в моем примере.

Comment: Переведите все в двоичный вид и увидите как работает

Comment: Как работает оператор xor написано в каждом учебнике информатики.

Comment: Хоr в программировании можно использовать если не ошибаюсь в двух случаях - 1) Шифрование (в т ч симметричным ключём)/хеширование/кодеки(некоторые)  2) В условиях в качестве "не равно" (при определённых условиях), но я бы всётаки писал оператор не равно.

Comment: https://habr.com/post/183462/ http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8, калькулятор http://xor.pw/ топ 10 гугла даёт хорошие результаты

Comment: Статьи я читал) 
1) я спросил не что такое `xor` а как его применять
2) и как работает конкретно мой пример. Про перевод в двоичный вид понял) спасибо

Comment: 1) Меняйте заголовок с "как работает" на "как применять". Выберите задачу, потому что применение можно показать на конкретной задаче. Вот я привел ссылку на хабр http://habr.com/post/183462/ там показано как применять. 2) После перевода в двоичную систему, стало понятно как работает на вашем примере?

Comment: стало понятно, откуда берется 3 при `1^2` и т.д.

Comment: Но почему он возвращает уникальный элемент (в данном случае 5) я не понимаю)

Comment: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4] = 001^010 ^ 011 .... переведите в двоичную систему и посчитайте в блокноте. Если 5 не выйдет - выложите расчёт ваш шаг-за-шагом - найдем ошибку. Я взял калькулятор винды, сделал хor - получил 5. В excel можно тоже посчитать такое.

Comment: Вот кстати  001^010 ^ 011 даёт всегда ноль, т.е. 1^2^3 = 0 тогда 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4 => 4,5,4. 4^4 = 0. Поэтому 4^5^4 = 0^5 = 5. Число само с собой - всегда даст ноль. Т.к. у вас 1,2,3,4 повторяются - то они "сокращаются". При хоr от перестановки аргументов - результат не меняется, можно делать его в любом порядке. 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4 => 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5 => 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Операция xor побитовая, т.е. обрабатывает каждый бит отдельно. Выпишите массив в бинарном виде в столбик

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0 
-----
5 4 5 
----
1 0 1
```

и посчитайте единицы в каждом столбце. Чётное число означает, что xor этих битов даст ноль в бите результата, а нечётное -  даст единицу. В результате `101b=5`